# JSONParseException when using Date in spring boot query anotation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, nosql

My document has attribute 'timestamp' and I want to get all older than n days.
The following query works just fine in mongodb shell:

```
{timestamp: { $gt: Date.now() - 1000*60*60*24*?0 } }
```

But when putting it inside Query anotation like this:

```
public interface TestRepo extends MongoRepository<TestEntry, String> {

    @Query("{timestamp: { $gt: Date.now() - 1000*60*60*24*?0 } }")
    Stream<TestEntry> get(Integer days);
}
```

I get json parse exception

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 

    {timestamp: { $gt: Date.now() - 1000*60*60*24?0 } }
                       ^
        at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:231) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.8.2.jar:na]



...
```

Comment: I guess this happens because it requires `JSON` and you have a `JavaScript` call inside. You have to use parameter and bind your's call value to it.

Comment: I could do that, but if the client and the database are in different time zones, it won't work. Is there another way to get the mongo current timestamp?

Comment: I prefer having everything on my servers in UTC. By the way, what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612203/how-to-run-mongodb-native-query-with-mongodb-date-function-in-spring-data-mongod ?